# Unable to consume HLS stream from AWS Kinesis feed in GStreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, amazon-kinesis, nvidia-deepstream

I’m trying to consume HLS feed generated by AWS Kinesis as input to DeepStream pipeline but I’m getting following error:

```
Error: gst-stream-error-quark: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.(1): qtdemux.c(7067):gst_qtdemux_process_adapter (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstBin:source-bin-00/GstURIDecodeBin:uri-decode-bin/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstQTDemux:
qtdemux1: no ‘moov’ atom within the first 10 MB
```

I’ve built the pipeline using python bindings and I’m using uridecodebin to resolve input URI. My GStreamer pipeline sequence is as follows:

```
uridecodebin --> nvstreammux --> nvinfer --> nvvideoconvert --> nvdsosd --> nveglglessink
```

Furthermore, I am also able to capture frames using a simple OpenCV python script. Following is my hardware configuration and software version:

- Hardware Platform (GPU) = NVIDIA T4
- DeepStream Version= 5.0
- TensorRT Version=7.0.0
- NVIDIA GPU Driver Version (valid for GPU only)=440.64.00

What should I do to get it working?

Comment: please add gstreamer pipeline plugin sequence you are using currently

Comment: Could you solve the above? Also @Tanmay, can you help me in this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031851/can-i-run-nvidia-deepstream-sdk-in-windows-server-2019